# Ask about the jsp inappropriate column name error

Tags: java, jsp

I'm writing a jsp code to connect Android studio with oracle database.
I created a new name_sql statement to get the name.
Login_fir_sql and login_sec_sql receive values normally when running in Android studios.
However, when executing the name_sql statement, an error called an inappropriate column name occurs.
How should I correct this error?

I posted a post here, so I set the ip address and ID password in that way to cover it.

Thank you.

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.sql.*"
    import = "java.util.*" %>

<%
    String login_fir_recvCode;
    String login_fir_recvNo;
    String login_fir_recvPwd;
    
    String login_sec_recvBirth;
    String login_sec_recvBusiness;
    
    String returns ="";
   
   try {
      login_fir_recvCode = request.getParameter("code");// android studio value
      login_fir_recvNo = request.getParameter("empno");// android studio value
      login_fir_recvPwd = request.getParameter("password");// android studio value
      
      login_sec_recvBirth = request.getParameter("birthday");// android studio value
      login_sec_recvBusiness = request.getParameter("business");// android studio value
      
      System.out.println(login_fir_recvCode);
      System.out.println(login_fir_recvNo);
      System.out.println(login_fir_recvPwd);
      System.out.println(login_sec_recvBirth);
      System.out.println(login_sec_recvBusiness);
      
      //DB Connect
      Connection conn = null;
      
      PreparedStatement login_fir_pstmt = null;
      PreparedStatement login_sec_pstmt = null;
      PreparedStatement name_pstmt = null;
      
      ResultSet login_fir_rs = null;
      ResultSet login_sec_rs = null;
      ResultSet name_rs = null;
      
      String login_fir_sql = null;
      String login_sec_sql = null;
      String name_sql = null;
      
      
      try {
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracl:thin:@ip address:orcl", "id", "password");
         try {
            login_fir_sql = "SELECT * FROM CREW WHERE CODE= ? AND EMP_NO=? AND PASSWORD=?";//Login
            login_sec_sql = "SELECT * FROM KFC_CREW WHERE BIRTHDAY=? OR BUSINESS_NUMBER=?";//second login use Birthday
            name_sql = "SELECT NAME FROM CREW WHERE EMP_NO=?";//call name
            
            login_fir_pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(login_fir_sql);
            login_sec_pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(login_sec_sql);
            name_pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(name_sql);
           
            login_fir_pstmt.setString(1,login_fir_recvCode);
            login_fir_pstmt.setString(2,login_fir_recvNo);
            login_fir_pstmt.setString(3,login_fir_recvPwd);
            
            login_sec_pstmt.setString(1,login_sec_recvBirth);
            login_sec_pstmt.setString(2,login_sec_recvBusiness);
            
            name_pstmt.setString(1,login_fir_recvNo);
     
            login_fir_rs = login_fir_pstmt.executeQuery();
            login_sec_rs = login_sec_pstmt.executeQuery();
            name_rs = name_pstmt.executeQuery();
 
            if (login_fir_rs.next()) {
            if (login_fir_rs.getString("CODE").equals(login_fir_recvCode) && login_fir_rs.getString("EMP_NO").equals(login_fir_recvNo) && login_fir_rs.getString("PASSWORD").equals(login_fir_recvPwd)) {
               returns = "2";
            } else {
               returns = "1";
            }
         }
            if (login_sec_rs.next()) {
               if (login_sec_rs.getString("BIRTHDAY").equals(login_sec_recvBirth)||login_sec_rs.getString("BUSINESS_NUMBER").equals(login_sec_recvBusiness)) {
                 returns = "4";
              } else {
                 returns = "3";
              }
           }
           if(name_rs.next()){
                if(name_rs.getString("EMP_NO").equals(login_fir_recvNo)){
                   returns=name_rs.getString("NAME");
                }
             }
         
         } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Oracle SELECT Error!"+e.getMessage());
            }
         } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Oracle connection failed.");
         }
      } catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Server or Oracle Error!");
   } finally {
      out.println(returns); 
   }
%>
```

This is stack Trace
java.sql.SQLException: Inappropriate column names.
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3724)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2799)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:498)
at org.apache.jsp.AndroidDB_jsp._jspService(AndroidDB_jsp.java:203)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)

Comment: Your query `SELECT NAME FROM CREW WHERE EMP_NO=?` probably uses a reserved keyword. Try it on a tool, and escape the column name.

Comment: I tried running it on the tool, but it works normally on the tool, and there seems to be no column corresponding to the reserved word.

Comment: Please post the complete error message and stack trace.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The "Inappropiate column" error happens at `getString`, so you must check that all your calls to `getString(column)` carry a column name which is available within the corresponding SQL.

In this way, you will find that the most suspicious call is

`name_rs.getString("EMP_NO")`

... because `name_rs` is built upon `name_sql`, wich does not include an `EMP_NO` field within the SELECT clause.

So, ensure that all the columns referenced in `get*(column)` calls ARE included within the SELECT clause.

Comment: How should I modify the code?

Comment: Read my last edit.